# Debounce on a React functional component when typing not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I have a form component, and I would like to perform an API request as I am typing.  I want to debounce this so I don't spam the server. Here is my code:

```
export default function MyItem ({ id, name }) {
  const debouncePatch = (name) => {
    debounce(patchItem.bind(this, id, name), 500)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        type='text'
        value={name}
        onChange={(evt) => debouncePatch(evt.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
)
}
```

The patch item does a simple patch call to the server so that the item's name updates as I am typing. It looks something like this:

```
export default function patchItem (id, name,) {
  return axios.patch(`${MY_BASE_URL}/${id}`, { name })
}
```

With the debounce it is not working at all. The `patchItem` function is never called. How can I fix this?

Comment: debounce returns a new function that is "debouncable". you are calling debounce in your handler not your debounced function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `debounce` on every change to the `input` but it just creates a new debounced function every time. You need to create a single debounced function and then use it as event handler. Like this:

```
function MyItem({ id, name }) {
  let debouncePatch = debounce((id, name) => {
    patchItem(id, name);
  }, 500);

  // OR SIMPLER
  let debouncePatch = _.debounce(patchItem, 500);
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        defaultValue={name}
        onChange={(event) => debouncePatch(id, event.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also make sure the input gets the `defaultValue` rather than `value` so it can be edited.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 issues here. Firstly, debounce *returns* a function, so you need to call that one.

Secondly, if you don't memoize the debounced function then it won't work properly, as each re-render will create a new debounced function, and thus defeat the point of debouncing.

Try something like this:

```
const debouncePatch = useCallback(debounce(() => patchItem(this, id, name), 500), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your input controllable,
and you can use simple utile **use-debounce**

```
import { useDebounce } from 'use-debounce';

export default function MyItem ({ id, name }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const [debouncedValue] = useDebounce(value, 1000);

  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {setValue(e.target.value)}, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(debouncedValue);
    *// here you can place any code what you need. **console.log** will be displayed every second, or any time that you may change in hook above.* 
  }, [debouncedValue])

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        type='text'
        value={name}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
)
}
```

ps. you do not have to use bind in your example for sure. and I am not sure you can apply onChange event to form